# Is it possible to convert a NUXT.js website to a WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, nuxt.js, wordpress-theming

I current have a website built using NUXT.js and was wondering if there is a quick way of converting it to a WordPress theme. without necessary rebuilding the WordPress theme from scratch.

Thanks